# Node-Mosca server, how to increase client expiration time?

Tags: node.js, mqtt

How can I keep the client's expiration time(disconnection time) to 15mins on mosca-broker side so that mosca should not close the socket until the client is idle for 15mins, by default this time is 01min on broker side. I know there is an option of setting 'checkFrequency' to the required time under LevelUp description but not sure if it works similarly also I could not find any example of its usage, so have little confusion. It will be great if you help me out.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is discussed on github.

https://github.com/mcollina/mosca/issues/430